# Centering the JInternalFrame in Netbeans GUI : setLocation() not working?

Tags: swing, user-interface, netbeans, jframe, jinternalframe

I'm creating a Desktop application using Netbeans GUI, i have created a JFrame and have added multipe Internalframes inside a desktop pane using the side palette. but the setLocation() method is not working at all. I'm dragging Internalframe from location to location to find the center on desktop pane..but it doesn't help.
how to do it..

```
public class HomeForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form HomeForm
 */

public HomeForm() {
    initComponents();
    setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);       
    jInternalFrame2.setLocation(GetScreenWorkingWidth()/3-50 , GetScreenWorkingHeight()/3-150);
    jInternalFrame2.setVisible(false);
    jInternalFrame2.setVisible(false);        
}

public static int GetScreenWorkingWidth() 
{
    return java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().width;
}

public static int GetScreenWorkingHeight() 
{
    return java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds().height;
}
}
```

I'm making these internalframes visible on button click!

Comment: Why writing GUI code if you are using the GUI builder?

Comment: cause it doesn't have any property related to centering internalframes..